# drag and drop text exercise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an exercise in which text id drag from div(contain words) then drop them into text-fields (these are 3)..Each field has its own text to be placed .. I have already drag and drop the text but cant able to compare them for particular fields .. Please help me.. Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
      #div2 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
      #div3 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
    </style>
    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev)
         {

            ev.preventDefault();
         }

       function drag(ev)
       {
           ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        }

       function drop(ev)
           {
              ev.preventDefault();
              var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
              ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
           }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    verbs
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>
    noun
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>
    adjetives
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">I play the guitar</div>
    <div id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">The piano is black</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should provide jsfiddle for better help

Comment: How Sir .. i have already use jsbin but cant find solution :(.. Please help me Sir..

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? what is meant by comparing?

Comment: Sir i want exercise like that
http://portalacademico.cch.unam.mx/alumno/tlriid2/unidad4/desviacionLenguajePoetico/Ejercicio3 .

Comment: How can we compare the dragged word with the text-field either the word suitable for text-field or not ?? Please help me Sir .. It will so kind of you ..

Comment: The exercise contain many words will have to be "dragged" to the boxes and "dropped" in the correct boxes. When the word is correct, there will be a check (✓). When the word is incorrect, there will be a message telling them to try again ... How can we compare word with the box?? Please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to change here.

**You need to drag words and not sentences**

```
<div id="drag1">I 
    <span id="play" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><b>play</b></span> the 
    <span id="guitar" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><b>guitar</b></span>
</div>
```

**There should be some list containing the allowed words for each type**

```
var nouns = ['guitar'];
var verbs = ['play'];
```

**Finally there should be a condition during drop event**

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    if(ev.target.id =='verb' && verbs.indexOf(data) != -1){
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    else{
        alert(data + ' is not a ' + ev.target.id +'. Try again');
    }

}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xptLU/) for a single sentence

Comment: Hi Sir Thanks a lot , i working but how can we use it for multiple words ??

Comment: How will you classify multiple words as nouns, verbs etc.?