# Put words in the right order to make a sentence with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816784/drag-and-drop-text-exercise) and I came up with an exercise I wanted to test.

There is an educational quiz where you have to put the words in the right order.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {background-color: black;}
    #div3 {margin-left: 0px;width:720px;height:200px;padding:50px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
      background-color: LightBlue;}
    span { margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background-color:#FFFF88; font-size: 50px;border: 0px solid;
      border-radius: 25px;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;}
    #quiz {margin-left: 0px;width:720px;height:200px;padding:40px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
      background-color: #FFFF88;}
    #quiz1 {border-radius: 0px;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: moz-none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
     <span id="word1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">the</span>
     <span id="word2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">piano</span>
     <span id="word3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">play</span>
     <span id="word4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">I</span>  
   </div>

   <script>
   function allowDrop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
   }
   function drag(ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
   }
   function drop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
   var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

code online:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmouzakitis/C2f4P/5/

Known Bugs 
 - Drag & drop of a word before first word is not possible
 - When you drag and drop a word near or over another word they become like one
   draggable object. I dont want that.

Is there another way to do it, using other javascript framework like angular.js, jQuery, other?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle.net and isolate your question to 1 problem.  Eliminate vague statements such as `there more bugs I can see` and `some css issues came up`

Comment: You're probably best off with an off-the-shelf solution styled to do what you want to do such as http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ in combination with the `sortable` function of jQuery UI

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: The original question was *"When you drag and drop a word near or over another word they become like one draggable"*. Since then the OP has changed the question so please see below (after the break) where I address the current question.

Here is how you could do it. I just needed to adjust your JavaScript slightly: http://jsbin.com/borexihi/1/edit?js,output

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    var currentText = $(ev.target).text();
    $(ev.target).text($('#' + data).text() + ' ' + currentText);
    $('#' + data).remove();
}
```

Note: my solution does use jQuery

---

**Answer for the current question**: The question has changed so the following is my answer to the updated version, which asks *"how to put the words given in the correct order"*.

Reordering items is a bit more tricky, which is why I would recommend using a library such as [jQuery UI's sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid).

I've created a JSBin for you that incorporates your code with the library: http://jsbin.com/giqoxitu/1/edit?html,css,js,output. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable" class="div3">
<li id="word1" class="ui-state-default">The</li>
<li id="word2" class="ui-state-default">piano</li>
<li id="word3" class="ui-state-default">play</li>
<li id="word4" class="ui-state-default">I</li>  
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {background-color: black;}

#sortable { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

#sortable li { 
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; 
  padding: 1px; 
  float: left; 
  width: 145px; 
  height: 90px; 
  font-size: 4em; 
  text-align: center; 
}

.div3 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  height:200px;
  padding:50px;
  border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background-color: LightBlue;
}

li { 
  margin: 20px; 
  padding: 20px; 
  border: 0px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Comment: did you try drop a word over another?

Comment: @MakisMouzakitis I did and they get combined. Did you look at my JSBin link?

Comment: I dont want to remove words. I want to rearrange the words and keep span formatting as it is.

Comment: @MakisMouzakitis Then your question isn't clear to me. It says: *"When you drag and drop a word near or over another word they become like one draggable".* This is what my example does. So, now you're saying you want to rearrange the words instead of combining them?

Comment: I updated the question. If you still dont understand let me know.

Comment: Thanks Sid. Your solution is fine.

Comment: @MakisMouzakitis Good to hear. Please remember to mark it as your chosen answer.